# Why are numbers sent from the web UI arriving in my MVC app as 'null;?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

I am sending a jQuery Ajax request as such:

```
$scope.geo.setSuburbs2 = function(areaId) {
    var idData = JSON.stringify({ 'areaId': 3, 'agentId': 1 });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Area/SuburbsJson",
        method: "POST",
        data: idData,
        dataType: "ajax"
    }).then(function(idData) {
            alert("Done!");
        },
        function(data, status) {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        });
};
```

This is supposed to fetch suburbs in ID `AreaId` serviced by an agent with ID `agentId`. The suburbs returned are key-value pairs in an array on the viewmodel. When I receive the model at the controller, all the keys are still correct in the array, but all numeric values are `null`.

When I send a `data` option from the `$.ajax` call that looks like:

```
{ 'areaId': 3, 'agentId': 1 }
```

I get the same size array of key-values on the web app, in `OnActionExecuting` in the controller, the above array item looks like:

```
{ 'areaId': null, 'agentId': null }
```

I strongly suspect a serialization problem on the browser, because the null values should not yet have arrived at my `JsonDotNet` custom (from the web) serializer. I normally only use that to improve serialization in POST resonses, when I send data back to the UI.

Is this some known problem, or do I have to pore through all the settings, a long list, on the `JsonDotNet` serializer? If it is a known problem, what should I do about it?

The viewmodel is `List<CheckListItemModel>`, where:

```
public class CheckListItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I don't use serialized viewmodels to talk between the controllers and the UI, I just pass a UI Angular controller function a filter ID for a list, and it returns the serialized list, with all numeric values set to `null`.

The action that sends the correct data to the UI is:

```
public JsonResult SuburbsJson(int areaId, int agentId)
{
    var allBurbs = _areaClient.GetSuburbs(areaId).ToList();
    var agentBurbIds = _agentClient.GetAgentSuburbs(agentId).Select(s => s.SuburbId).ToList();
    var model = new List<CheckListItemModel>();
    foreach (var burb in allBurbs)
    {
        model.Add(new CheckListItemModel { Id = burb.SuburbId, Label = burb.SuburbName, IsChecked = agentBurbIds.Contains(burb.SuburbId) });
    }
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

It's a question of `Id` and `IsChecked`. And item is already checked if its `Id` is in a list of Agents associated with that `SuburbId`.

Comment: Show the action and any model it depends on.

Comment: Try quoting the JSON object keys with double quotes instead of single quotation marks e.g. JSON.stringify({"areaId": 3, "agentId": 1})

Comment: The action isn't at play here. The data without the numerics is coming from the browser. The action sends the correct data, with correct numeric values. But, I put it in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON
>   string,

Recheck your payload construction. you need to stringify actual JavaScript object like...

```
$scope.geo.setSuburbs2 = function(areaId) {
       var value = { areaId: 3, agentId: 1 }; //Object to be sent to controller
       var idData = JSON.stringify(value);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Area/SuburbsJson",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: idData            
    }).then(function(idData) {
            alert("Done!");
        },
        function(data, status) {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        });
};
```

by removing the single quotes on the keys. Also note the changes to how the request was made to the controller.

Comment: I'm now using the more compatible Angular `$http.post`, but you are correct.